# Let {An} be a sequence of events such that An → A as n → ∞. Show that PAn → PA as n → ∞.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Let $\{A_{n}\}$ be a sequence of events such that $A_{n} → A$ as n → ∞. Show that $PA_{n}$ → PA as $n → ∞$.
If $A_{n}$ is nondecreasing or nonincreasing, it would be very easy. But what about an arbitrary convergent sequence of events.

Comment: Hint: Think about how one defines convergence of sets (events).

Comment: To use what you already know about monotonic limits, you need to note that liminf of the $A_n$ is an increasing limit of the $\cap_{k\geq n} A_k$, and limsup is a decreasing limit of the $\cup_{k \geq n} A_k$. That gets you some inequalities which are connected by the fact that $\liminf A_n = \limsup A_n = A$. This result is number 8 in 2.1 of Resnick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\limsup A_n = \bigcap_{n\geq 1} \bigcup_{k\geq n} A_k$ and $\liminf A_n = \bigcup_{n\geq1}\bigcap_{k\geq n} A_k$. We say that $A_n\to A$ if $A=\limsup A_n = \liminf A_n$.

The trick is to notice that (the proof is in the end of this answer)
$$P(\liminf A_n) \leq \liminf P(A_n) \leq \limsup P(A_n) \leq P(\limsup A_n).$$

If $A_n\to A$, we have $A=\liminf A_n =\limsup A_n$, thus $$P(A)\leq \liminf P(A_n)\leq \limsup P(A_n)\leq P(A)$$ and therefore $$\lim P(A_n) = \liminf P(A_n)=\limsup P(A_n)= P(A),$$ as desired.

---

*Proof:* It's clear that $\liminf P(A_n)\leq\limsup P(A_n)$. We are going to prove that $\limsup P(A_n) \leq P(\limsup A_n)$ (the proof for $\liminf$ is similar).

Notice that $B_n = \bigcup_{k\geq n} A_k$ satisfies $B_{n+1}\subseteq B_n$ and $A_n\subseteq B_n$ for all $n\geq 1$. Besides, $\lim B_n=\bigcap_{n\geq1} B_n=\limsup A_n$.

Thus $P(A_n)\leq P(B_n)\to P(\limsup A_n)$ for all $n\geq1$ and therefore $\limsup P(A_n)\leq P(\limsup A_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Show the inequality
$$
P(\liminf A_n)\leq \liminf P(A_n)\leq \limsup P(A_n)\leq P(\limsup A_n).
$$
The proof is very analogous to showing Fatou's lemma as a consequence of the monotone convergence theorem.